# How to install Ubuntu (any version) on my laptop (MSI GE72-6QF-073)?

Tags: system-installation, msi

I try to install the Ubuntu version 14.04 14.10 15.04 15.10 16.04 ,but all failed.

Only one time, I success install 14.04, but it is too lagging and not smooth to use. So I reinstalled it , and it failed.

And I can't log in to the Windows 10 system at last, so I sent the computer to the sale support..

Dose MSI laptop support Ubuntu system ?

Comment: You can give more details about how did you try to install Ubuntu ? Did you use a bootable USB drive  and if yes , how did you make it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

You're actual question really relates to supported hardware. [This link](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/ch02s01.html) is to the supported hardware section of the Ubuntu installation guide (for x64) and this should help you confirm the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a MSI GE72-6QF-073, but i had an older MSI 12.6' ultrabook which ran LinuxMint and Lubuntu very well. I see no reason why a gaming laptop like yours could not run Ubuntu smoothly.
Why send laptop to sale support? You should run a Windows installation DVD/USB disk and choose Repair Windows option. Ubuntu is liter than Windows, therefore it should run better and faster than Windows.